# How can I read this CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file with the following format:

```
"1512";"Wreaths";"";"1493";"1";"0";"2"
"1513";"Wrist Rests";"";"1494";"1";"0";"2"
"1514";"Wrist Watches";"";"1495";"1";"0";"2"
"1515";"Writing";"";"1496";"1";"0";"2"
"1516";"Writing, Research & Publishing Guides";"";"1497";"1";"0";"2"
"1517";"xD-Picture Cards";"";"1498";"1";"0";"2"
"1518";"Yogurt Makers";"";"1499";"1";"0";"2"
"1519";"Yucatan Peninsula";"";"1500";"1";"0";"2"
"1520";"Zip Discs";"";"1501";"1";"0";"2"
"1521";"Zurnas";"";"1502";"1";"0";"2"
```

Every record is on a different line and I would like to read it using PHP to import it to my database. Here is my code, which doesn't print out anything at all.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("all_cats.csv", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached

while(!feof($file))
{
    $line =  fgets($file);
    $json = json_decode($line, true);
    $json[0];
}
fclose($file);
```

Please let me know what you think and what I should do to get this to work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fgetcsv` to retrieve data.Please [refer](http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/how-to-import-csv-file-in-your-php-application/) this site.

Comment: thanks that helps a lot! Im reading it now and it surely teaches me exactly what I wanted to know! I appreciate your reply

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you need to use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php), with the delimeter `;` as per file/data

```
<?php
$file = fopen("all_cats.csv", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
echo '<pre>';
while(!feof($file))
{
    $line =  fgetcsv($file, 0, ';');
    print_r($line);
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fgetcsv function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num Felder in Zeile $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Please, change url to `en`-version.